# Referencing a versioned CSS file in my app.js file for Symfony

Tags: symfony, webpack, tinymce

I'm utilizing tinyMCE in my Symfony application and I need to reference a compiled CSS file in my app.js file.

For tinyMCE, the reference command is `content_css : tinymcecss`

I've tried including the file like I do for iconography like so:

```
import plusicon from '../images/icons/plus.svg';
import tinymcecss from '../sass/email_styles.scss';
```

However the error I get back is `export 'default' (imported as 'tinymcecss') was not found in '../sass/email_styles.scss' (module has no exports)`.

What is the proper way of referencing a compiled CSS file (from SASS) in my app.js file for Symfony?

Answer (score 1):

The `content_css` configuration option expects a URL (path) to a CSS file - not a variable name to something bundled into your application.  The CSS file is then loaded into the iframe that is TinyMCE so that the CSS impacts the content but not the page of your application that embeds TinyMCE.

You can do something similar to what you were trying do via importing the CSS but you need to use `content_style` not `content_css`:

```
/* Import content css */
 import contentUiCss from '../tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.css';
 import contentCss from '../tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css';

 /* Initialize TinyMCE */

    tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea#editor',
     plugins: 'advlist code emoticons link lists table',
     toolbar: 'bold italic | bullist numlist | link emoticons',
     skin: false,
     content_css: false,
     content_style: contentUiCss.toString() + '\n' + contentCss.toString(),
   });
```

Please see the TinyMCE documentation on using module loaders for further details:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/introduction_to_bundling_tinymce/

Comment: So what happens if the output CSS file that is being compiled by webpack and is versioned with every compile? How do you make sure that the file is referencing the right version?

Comment: If the file you create changes the name each time you build it you either have to (a) change your `content_css` in your TinyMCE init or use the alternative approach using `content_style` as you are no longer referencing the file at runtime.